# Replace scrollbar with dots

Tags: html, css, scroll

Not sure if anyone can help or if it's possible. I don't have any code written as of yet but if someone is willing to help me out, it would be much appreciated.

I have a modal. It has a lot of icons in it and I have set the modal to a width and height. It has given me a scrollbar which is intended. I am wondering if it is possible to remove the scrollbar and replace it with dots.

I have done some research and all I can find is it can be done but only on full site webpages where I have a modal.[image: Modal scrollbar dots]

If it can be done and no one wants to assist, I can understand, and therefore I will return with what I have tried to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a webkit browser you should be able to hide the scrollbar elements other than the buttons and style those buttons to be dots (using ::webkit-scrollbar and whatnot). Otherwise you could hide the scrollbar and create a custom one out of two dot buttons.

Comment: Actually I realised that replacing the scrollbar with only buttons is probably not what you're looking for because they'd scroll the same way the arrows do on a normal scrollbar. If that is what you were looking for then that's how you'd do it but it may even be easier to cut out the webkit because hiding the rest of the scrollbar is a little difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can hide the scrollbar with CSS (in webkit browsers as Sam mentioned):
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

And then you can implement the up and down arrow buttons to change the vertical scroll amount of your modal component using an intermediate value to record where the current `top` is (and then disable the up/down button when already at the top or bottom, or ensure that if the user keeps clicking up/down when already at the top or bottom, the `top` isn't negative or excessively large such that the next correct click doesn't immediately scroll the correct amount):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll

```
HTML:
<div id="modal">
    My numerous buttons that require scrolling.
</div>


CSS:
#modal::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


JS:
let top = 0;
const scrollAmount = 25;
const height = 500;
const totalHeight = 5000;

function scrollModalTo(top) {
    document.getElementById('modal').scroll({
      top,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}

function scrollUp() {
    if (top !== 0) {
        top -= scrollAmount;
        top = Math.max(0, top);
        scrollModalTo(top);
    }
}

function scrollDown() {
    if (top < totalHeight - height) {
        top += scrollAmount;
        top = Math.min(top, totalHeight-height);
        scrollModalTo(top);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input mirage.
This is a good start and have already implemented the code. I will work on the changes as I go.
Cheers.